# Should "nookcolor" really be a synonym of "nook"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Perhaps I'm splitting hairs a bit here, but I noticed just now that [nookcolor](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nookcolor) is a synonym of [nook](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nook). While on the one hand I can understand why this was probably done, part of me feels like this is, in essence, not correct. For one, they are not the same device, so it seems kind of unintuitive that they are pointing to each other like this. Secondly, it is [entirely possible to root a "Nook Classic"](http://nookdevs.com/Nook_Classic_Rooting_Methods) and the rooting method is different than [that of the Nook Color](http://nookdevs.com/NookColor_Rooting). Clearly there is potential for relevant rooting questions on each, if nothing else, though I can certainly imagine other questions for each being very different as well.

So, should this synonym really exist? Even if there are no valid [nook](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nook) questions at the moment, I feel like they should be separate tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds right to me.  The new tag is [nook-color](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nook-color) with no synonyms.  Two questions were about the app, and are now tagged with [nook-for-android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nook-for-android) instead.

Comment: Awesome. And Nook for Android is a good point, too. That's also very different.